# PHP to Excel special characters problem

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to use code that i found on some website to convert mysql to excel.

Here is link to the code i am trying to use:

http://www.phpsimple.net/tutorials/mysql_to_excel/

When i try to save excel it works fine it there are no special characeters.

But it converts following data from mysql

ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧

into this in excel

Ã‡Ã¼Ã©Ã¼Ã¢Ã¤Ã Ã¥Ã§ÃªÃ«Ã¨Ã¯Ã®Ã¬Ã„Ã„Ã‰Ã´Ã¶Ã²Ã»Ã¹Ã¿Ã–ÃœÆ’Ã¡Ã±Ã‘Î±ÃŸÎ“Î£Î©Î´âˆžÏ†Îµâˆ©Â£Â¥â‚§

and for text below from mysql it doesnt display anything in excel file.

ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαßΓΣΩδ∞φε∩£¥₧ 
ÇüéüâäàåçêëèïîìÄÄÉôöòûùÿÖÜƒáñÑαß

I tried setting following additional header but it didnt help :

`header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8; encoding=UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved with adding UTF16-LE as encoding type. Text is still missing for second part i looks like its something in relation to code i am using and line breaks in the text so i will debug it and see if i can fix it.